# How do I auto update a field in Django

Tags: django

I have a Model:

```
class Development(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    logno = models.CharField(max_length=13, unique=True)
    insurer = models.ForeignKey(InsName, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False, verbose_name="Client")
    policy = models.ManyToManyField(Policy, blank=True)
    platform = models.ManyToManyField(Platform)
    documents = models.ManyToManyField(Document)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Within the development detail template I want a button that when clicked changes the active field from True to False. I cannot find a simple way of doing this. I know I need to do something in my VIEWS.PY but I'm not sure what. The button is currently:

```
<form action="" method = "POST">
    <input type="submit" name="archive" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Archive" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the django [updateview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView)

Comment: This just shows how to pull up an update template. I want to cut out the manual step of changing the field on the update template and just force change the active field for that record